# checkbox with CSS3 decorated that added dynamically by JQuery doesn't shown correctly

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic

I have html as below:

```
<ul class="group">
    <label class="category">
        <div class="lightpoint">
                <input type="checkbox" class="parentB" value="{{>name}}" /><label></label>
        </div>
    </label>
    <li>
        <div class="lightpoint">
                <input type="checkbox" class="childB" value="{{>name}}" ><label></label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Above html snippets was dynamically added by Jquery.

javascript:

```
$('.parentB').on("click", function(event){
                var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
                $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find('.childB').attr("checked", isChecked);
    });
```

I checked the change of html in firebug by using firefox. The '.childB''s checked state is truely modified when '.parentB' is clicked. But looks nothing happens. I mean it should looks with the corresponding checked state, but actually not.

It that caused by CSS3?

**Now i have the answer. I don't make myself very clearly. The jquery verison that i used is 1.9.0, that is only about the jquery version. It goes well when i changed it to 1.8.3.**

Answer (score 0):

`.parentB` doesn't exist when that script is executed and so no handler is actually getting bound.

You have 2 options,

1. Use delegated event by binding the handler to the parent element and look for target element. Don't worry, with right syntax.. jQuery does this nicely for you.. See below,

   ```
   $(document).on('click', '.parentB', function(event){
      var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
      $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find('.childB').attr("checked", isChecked);
   });
   ```
2. Bind the handler after you append those dynamic html to the DOM.

Point 2 is preferable in most cases, but in some cases 1 is better.

Comment: I did bind handler after append dynamic html to the DOM. actually it works by checking in inspect element, when '.parentB' is checked, '.childB' is also checked as well, but i mean, on the view page, '.childB' doesn't look checked. the '.childB' checkbox doesn't shown in checked way.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid html `ul` should have `li` as direct child so put. Your script is working though but change html needs changed script

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/DBx2k/)**

```
<ul class="group">
   <li>  
    <label class="category">
        <div class="lightpoint">
            <input type="checkbox" class="parentB" value="{{>name}}" />
            <label></label>
        </div>
    </label>
    </li>   
    <li>
        <div class="lightpoint">
            <input type="checkbox" class="childB" value="{{>name}}">
            <label></label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

$('.parentB').on("click", function (event) {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $(this).closest('li').next('li').find('.childB').attr("checked", isChecked);
});
```

Comment: I tried your proposal, it still looks nothing happens. But as i asked before, the checked state indeed updated by checking in inspect element. just look and feel is not correct.